# How best to procrastinate and learn LaTeX?

Tags: latex-misc

Slightly tongue-in-cheek this one but written in good faith...

I am a competent user of LaTeX and use it with Eclipse as IDE, MacTexlive as install, and XeTeX as engine to author my PhD.

However, there are times when I like to procrastinate and love LaTeX as an end in itself not just as a means to an end.  What would you recommend as a good way of procrastinating whilst usefully extending my capabilities and abilities to use LaTeX?

In the past SVN, biber and beamer have served to distract me from my thesis.  Any more potentially fruitful areas?

Comment: Try to answer questions on this site! I find that the best way to learn about a wide range of issues, and get really good, constructive and quick feedback from experienced users.

Comment: Of course there are :D Try TikZ/pgf. You can create great graphics for your Phd while procrastinating ;-) Also there are over 700 pages of manual you can read.

Comment: Ah, philosophy of education thesis.  80K words and no pictures.

Comment: Be careful what you wish for :)

Comment: Draw the algorithm of the LaTeX `output` routine in TikZ.

Comment: LaTeX3 is very good for procrastination.

Comment: There's always the `memoir` and the `biblatex` manuals you can read in your spare time. Then you can try all of the features they provide and you don't really need :)

Comment: Now `memoir` does look tempting!

Comment: study and try to understand the [questions tagged with expansion](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expansion)

Comment: Just don't do it. Get out into nature and take some fresh air. And then back to your real project :-)

Comment: Rewrite your university's thesis format into a proper LaTeX class. That's a tougher task in the U.S. than elsewhere, but still worthwhile.

Comment: After you've plowed through the `memoir` and `biblatex` reference guides and the entire `LaTeX3` project documentation, turn to `LuaTeX` and `LuaLaTeX` and its manuals. :-)

Comment: I had never used LaTeX until my thesis but wanted to learn it and it was a perfect opportunity. You have perfectly articulated why I probably would finish faster if I used notepad++ instead...

Comment: As you are asking for other fruitful areas for procrastination: Consider switch from [SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) to [git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) or [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial_%28software%29).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You probably had some customization  in your thesis.  Try to make a package of your code, publish it on CTAN and then support it, answering users' requests.

This will definitely help you to learn TeX and to procraste in your other activity.

At least this advice works for me.

Comment: You're right; previous answers have helped me customise my bibliography and provide word counts for specific sections of text without detexing and/or parsing through some other external program.

Answer (score 28):

Get yourself a book on typography, e.g. [The Elements of Typographic Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Typographic_Style), and try to improve your thesis. Be critical about the things mentioned, and try to implement the things you'd like to see in your thesis.

Answer (score 12):

I found that learning [TikZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ) a wonderful way of expanding my knowledge of Latex and vector graphics. It also had the handy side affect that the diagrams and charts in my masters project report looked beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

comb through the package library and grab all those packages involving typography, lines/shapes, layout, displaystyle, formatting, etc...

Also, you can \define and \redefine as many things as possible. It makes proof readers of your tex file want to strangle you with all the new definitions and packages to install. :p

Answer (score 1):

... as I relished the post I immediately thought of (1) TikZ/PGF, closely followed by (2) LaTeX3, then noticed with little surprise that both topics had already been suggested. Time consuming they may be, time wasters they are not!